# Changing Appmaker deployment owner

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there *any* way to change the deployment owner of an Appmaker application?

The person who has created Appmaker applications for our organization is leaving, and we need to have new owners for the deployments. The options for exporting data, viewing logs, publishing and editing deployment details (e.g. admins) are only available to the deployment owner, so managing the deployment is close to impossible without the deployment owner.

Also, I'm wondering what will happen when the account of the deployment owner's account is deleted. Does the deployment disappear or is it just a deployment without an owner?

Could a Google admin transfer the ownership, even though it is not possible for the normal user?

If you have any other suggestions on how to deal with this problem, I'm happy to hear them out.

EDIT: I have tried transferring the Appmaker file to a different owner but that has no effect on the deployments.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/appmaker-users/deployment$20owner%7Csort:date/appmaker-users/rESys-htyCs/ArxhJ1r1DwAJ

Comment: Thanks! Something unusual happened with the link though, here's what I think you meant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/appmaker-users/%E2%80%A60owner%7Csort:date/appmaker-users/rESys-htyCs/ArxhJ1r1DwAJ - the issue still remains though, even if transferring ownership is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried just transferring ownership of the project to someone else? Meaning assigning a different owner as you can do with any other file in Drive.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa actually I have, but that has no effect on the deployments. Thanks, I'm going to edit that into the post.

Comment: So the only possible workarounds at this time would be to transfer ownership of the project, then create a new deployment and set up a custom database that points to the same database under the deployment owned by someone else and maybe implement a redirect from the previous URL to the new URL. This is obviously not ideal and the AM team should put a higher priority on this, considering how long this issue has existed. The alternative, although this would not work for existing deployments, have your Admin create a separate email that all AM projects run through.